# How to allow the emulator to access internet in android?

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

How to allow the android emulator to access internet ?

Comment: To answer your question, we need more details. In my experience, accessing the internet often works out of the box. However, if you are behind a proxy, it requires some configuration. How is your computer connected to the internet?

Comment: Thanks Bendik. Its working by just set the user-permission in MANIFEST.<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to set any setting to access internet on emulator unless you are behind a proxy, in case you are behind a proxy start your emulator from command prompt with following command:  C:/emulator -avd avdname -http-proxy http://your.proxy.ip:8080

Comment: Go to Control Panel-> Network Connections -> your connection(right-click)-> properties -> Select Tab General -> Check Radio Tcp/IP -> Properties-> you can get proxy settings here

Comment: that displays IP,Default Gateway and subnet mask address only.NO proxy address details are there. It shows some additional DNS address.

Comment: then its okay you are not behind any proxy.

Comment: I want change the syntax or else it will run by default

Comment: I found my proxy address BoSS:) Thank U