# Accessing Internet from Emulator in Android

Tags: android, emulation

[image]I am trying to access internet (http://www.google.co.in/) through my project say "WebViewDemo".
It works fine in device but not in emulator.
I am able to access internet (http://www.google.co.in/) through the browser of the emulator. But my project displays "`Web Page is not available`".

I am behind a proxy.  I have added INTERNET permission in the AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: can you please come here for more conversion http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6137/

Comment: i dint get the solution for this yet!

Comment: Try removing the proxy settings

Comment: it doesn't work if there is no proxy..

Comment: then contact your network admin and ask him for running without proxy

Comment: Hey @Sneha, please check answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818856/how-to-allow-the-emulator-to-access-internet-in-android/8818992#8818992

Comment: I am getting avd / emulator is not an external command error when i try this : D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>emulator avd aaaa -http-proxy http://my-proxy-ip:8080

Comment: oh.. still your problem has not been solved. have you tried another computer ?

Comment: yes.. tried with many computers..same problem!

Comment: Please join my chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6137/

Answer (score 1):

No need to add any thing for getting internet on emulator , if you have internet for your PC, you can get internet on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

you can toggle internet by pressing F8 button. Try to tern it on... you will able to see 3G symbole in status bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In Eclipse:

Window>Preferences>Android>Launch

In the Default emulator options, put the value -dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4

If this does not work, check this post
[How to set Internet options for Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2437366/1244489)